# Composer installation questions

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to get my head around how to install composer. Really confusing!

I have downloaded the windows installer and during the installation was asked to locate "php.exe". Does that mean I need to have a local server (Wamp) installed?

Lets say I manage to install composer on my PC. How do I get it to work on my web host? Do i copy files there or do I need to install composer on web host as well?

Answer (score 2):

Composer requires php executable, but not webserver. So installing php from [php site](http://php.net/downloads.php) is sufficient. However, if you plan to develop or run php applications on your computer, you would prefer to install full stack (eg wamp) right away.

Composer is needed only to install and update dependencies, once you do it, all are just files, and you transfer them as you transfer other files to your webhost. So copy, no need to install composer on web host.

Comment: Well how to install composer in the LAMP?

Comment: @Keynes, be sure php binary is in your %Path% and follow installation instructions for windows.